# Can I run a kernel newer than 5.15 on Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4b?

Tags: drivers, kernel, raspberrypi, camera

I've got a Raspberry Pi 4b 4GB running Ubuntu 22.04 server (kernel 5.15) that I run ROS2 Humble on for robotics (which necessitates 22.04). I recently bought a Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 to use as a camera for my robot, however it does not function correctly on this OS. I validatd  this hardware combination by running Raspbian, where the camera worked perfectly.

In [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/551) I tried to work out how to make it work, and was told that the kernel I'm running does not contain the necessary drivers for the Sony IMX758 sensor. I was advised that a newer kernel version might solve my problems and have the drivers built in.

Thus far I have been copying changes from [raspberrypi/linux](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) over to the [Ubuntu provided linux-raspi kernel](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/) on the branch [applied/ubuntu/jammy-updates 5.15.0-1035.38 (patches applied)](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/commit/?h=applied/ubuntu/jammy-updates). This has only partially worked, and not ended up enabling the camera.

Can I run a kernel newer than 5.15 with ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)? I notice that there's a 6.2.X kernel in the Ubuntu rpi-kernel repo tagged with mantic (23.10) and lunar (23.04).  If so, does it matter whether I get the newer kernel from [raspberrypi/linux](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) (which has 6.1y branch, that I think I would have to recompile, or Ubuntu's [linux-raspi kernel](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/), and would either choice be better?

AFAIK the kernel goes under any distro-specific customization, so in theory could I simply compile 6.1y from [raspberrypi/linux](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) and apply the .deb patches to Ubuntu?

If anyone can advise on next steps it would be wonderful. There are error logs in my linked [GitHub issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/551) and more diagnostics.

Comment: Why don't you just use https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/linux-generic-hwe-22.04  as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is a LTS release, thus kernel stack options exist (ie. kernels from 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 will become available)  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details (or see answer below), with the *default* kernel stack choice set by your install media.  Also note there are *distro-specific* customizations (ubuntu-sauce) to kernels too !

Comment: @guiverc I used apt to install the package you linked to first (the generic hwe kernel), however it did not work for me, as even after I reboot I still boot into 5.15.0-1035-raspi. 
See my response to the below answer by Artur Melind for more details. 

If you have any ideas on how to troubleshoot or what approach I should take if compiling my own kernel is required, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The response I referenced was deleted, so here it is repasted:
This didn't work for me on the raspberry pi. I believe I need kernels ending in raspi not generic. I found this related mailing list The install process worked but the kernel didn't install. It went to /boot/ but not /boot/firmware I don't have room to attach terminal snips in this comment due to char limit :( so i've linked it https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/files/12432295/hwe_kernel_rpi_not_work.txt

Comment: @guiverc I was wrong to assume the HWE kernel line works on Raspberry Pi - it doesn't, so that's why I deleted my answer. I think the only solution here is to compile your own kernel. I'm not sure what would be good sources to get started with this.

Comment: Jeff Geerling has a number of guides and videos about compiling kernel for various odd hardware for the Pi - maybe it can help. https://github.com/geerlingguy

Answer (score 2):

I was able to update my kernel to 6.2.0-1004-raspi by installing the package [linux-image-6.2.0-1004-raspi](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/kernel/linux-image-6.2.0-1004-raspi) using apt. This updated my kernel with precompiled images.

I was able to access this package by adding Ubuntu lunar sources to `/etc/apt/sources-list`. I added the following lines:

```
# adding this to get the new 6.2.x kernel from lunar
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar-updates main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar-updates universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar-updates multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar-backports main restricted 
universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports lunar-security multiverse
```

I then simply did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install linux-image-6.2.0-1004-raspi`, and rebooted when the installation was done.

```
atticus@rospi:~  
$ uname -a
Linux rospi 6.2.0-1004-raspi #5-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 11:15:14 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

The updated kernel did not solve the problem I set out to fix, as my Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 still does not work on this Ubuntu install, despite the correct drivers being present, but I will create a new post regarding that.

```
atticus@rospi:~  
$ libcamera-hello 
Preview window unavailable
[0:13:33.922153143] [5185]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.1.0+19-960d0c1e
[0:13:33.961853643] [5186] ERROR V4L2 v4l2_device.cpp:93 'imx708': Failed to open V4L2 device '': No such file or directory
[0:13:33.961984865] [5186] ERROR RPI vc4.cpp:209 Failed to register camera imx708: -22
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

Comment: It can be a little dangerous to mix in sources for newer Ubuntu releases into 22.04.